# Is there a way to get a Session Id from a HTTPS request in node?

Tags: javascript, session, https

I cannot figure out how. I make an HTTPS get request, but I just get a long list of information, but no SessionId

Here is the code I have written in node.js I have replaced my API with a fake one, but other things are the same.

```
 var http = require('http');
//var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var https = require('https')
var readline = require('readline');
var url = require('url')
var request = require('request')

var body = ""

process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";

var options = {
    url: "https://SOMEAPI.com/us/oauth/v2/authorize?SOMEPATH",
    host: "SOMEAPI.com"
}

var cookie = https.get(options, (response) => {
    response.on(('data'), (chunk) => {
        body += chunk
    })
    response.on('end', () => {
        //printSession(response)
        //console.log(response)
    })
})

console.log(cookie)
```

This is my console output:

```
Debugger listening on [::]:5858
ClientRequest {
  domain: null,
  _events:
   { response: { [Function: g] listener: [Function] },
     socket: { [Function: g] listener: [Function: onSocket] } },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  output: [ 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: [https://SOMEAPI.com]\r\nConnect
ion: close\r\n\r\n' ],
  outputEncodings: [ 'latin1' ],
  outputCallbacks: [ [Function: finish] ],
  outputSize: 77,
  writable: true,
  _last: true,
  upgrading: false,
  chunkedEncoding: false,
  shouldKeepAlive: false,
  useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
  sendDate: false,
  _removedHeader: {},
  _contentLength: 0,
  _hasBody: true,
  _trailer: '',
  finished: true,
  _headerSent: true,
  socket: null,
  connection: null,
  _header: 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: [https://SOMEAPI.com]\r\nConnecti
on: close\r\n\r\n',
  _headers: { host: '[https://SOMEAPI.com]' },
  _headerNames: { host: 'Host' },
  _onPendingData: null,
  agent:
   Agent {
     domain: null,
     _events: { free: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     defaultPort: 443,
     protocol: 'https:',
     options: { path: null },
     requests: {},
     sockets: { 'https://SOMEAPI.com:443::::::::[https': [Object] },
     freeSockets: {},
     keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
     keepAlive: false,
     maxSockets: Infinity,
     maxFreeSockets: 256,
     maxCachedSessions: 100,
     _sessionCache: { map: {}, list: [] } },
  socketPath: undefined,
  timeout: undefined,
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  _ended: false }
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://SOMEAPI.com https://SOMEAPI.com:443
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
Press any key to continue...
```

Edit: Here is what I am at now:

```
Debugger listening on [::]:5858
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Policy Falsified</faultstring>
            <faultactor>https://SOMEAPI.com/</faultactor>
            <detail>
                <l7:policyResult
                    status="Service Not Found.  The request may have been sent t
o an invalid URL, or intended for an unsupported operation." xmlns:l7="http://ww
w.layer7tech.com/ws/policy/fault"/>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Policy Falsified</faultstring>
            <faultactor>https://SOMEAPI.com/</faultactor>
            <detail>
                <l7:policyResult
                    status="Service Not Found.  The request may have been sent t
o an invalid URL, or intended for an unsupported operation." xmlns:l7="http://ww
w.layer7tech.com/ws/policy/fault"/>
            </detail>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I believe this is header info that might be important:

```
REQUEST
GET https://SOMEAPI.com/us/oauth/v2/authorize?SOMEPATH HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml
Host: SOMEAPI.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Comment: the so called `SessionID` would be something the server sends, if you don't "see" one in the "long list of information" you are either looking in the wrong place (it's likely to be a cookie perhaps) or the server isn't sending anything called a SessionID

Comment: I'm looking at the site on Postman and there is a sessionId in the html. is is like <input type="hidden" name="sessionID" value="4afeaefafefetc" />

Comment: How can I get that value?

Comment: so, you were mistaken where you said `but no SessionId` - simple regex should be able to extract the required info

Comment: It seems like the info I am getting on POSTMan doesn't really resemble what I am getting back from my HTTPS get. Could it be because it is hidden?

Comment: Wait, so maybe I shouldn't be using an HTTPS .get, right? Since the value is in the html.

Comment: well, how else would you `GET` the page - HTTP vs HTTPS is irrelevant

Comment: I think what I'm looking at is not what I think it is. It is a list of stuff like socketPath, method, path, agent (lots of agent stuff),  headers, header, etc. And then it throws an error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

Comment: this is why you should post **code** you are having trouble with ... saying `I just get a long list of information` doesn't exactly show what information **you** are looking at - chances are, it's the *wrong* information

Comment: I just updated it. Please let me know if you see what is wrong. I have been working on this for a very long time. :(

Comment: what does `response.on('end', () => { console.log(body); })` output?

Comment: the getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND at the bottom of the console output above

Comment: it also says "events.js:160      throw err;" above that, but thats it

Comment: how can that be? you were getting that error **before** you console.log(body) ???

Comment: `host: "https://SOMEAPI"` that looks wrong ... shouldn't it be `host: "SOMEAPI.com"` - i.e. the same **host** as in the url?

Comment: Yea my bad, it still doesn't do anything though :( Below this comment I put some header info I found that I need to use to access I think. I've tried it to no avail

Comment: GET https://SOMEAPI.com/SOMEPATH HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml
Host: SOMEAPI.com
Connection: Keep-Alive

Comment: what is this last comment supposed to be?

Comment: OH CRAP I changed the host by taking out the "https" and I got some xml/http. I'm going to post it above. It isn't quite what I need, but I feel closer.

Comment: I added everything above. The last bit might be stuff I need to add into my "options", but I am unsure.

Comment: your `options` looks funky, with a path `/` - clearly **not** the path of the request

Comment: I just changed it to what I have for my options now that got me to the XML. I assume it has gone so far as to gotten to the end of the link, where the URL is. Do I need to include the "HTTP 1.1" thing?

Comment: https `options` does not take a `url` property - seems in this **simple** case, you could use a string for options, `var options = "https://SOMEAPI.com/us/oauth/v2/authorize?SOMEPATH";`

Comment: IT WORKED!! I now have the html code with javascript and stuff! How do i go about extracting a value that is enclosed within the html code? Do I have to figure out what line it is on or what? it is in the middle of a bunch of messy HTML and it says "<input type="hidden" name="sessionID" value="dde48bea-76f7-491c-9bb5-6782551bfa6" />"    I need the value string. How do i extract it?

Comment: as I said an hour ago - imple regex should be able to extract the required info

Comment: Awesome. I'll look into it. I guess I'll loop through the string and when I get to "sessionID" I will move 9 characters past and then append a string until I get to the last quotation mark. Thank you so much for your help. You should post like a short answer saying you helped me in the comments, so I can give you credit for giving me an answer!